How to Fix Mixed Content Error When Proxying Requests to Backend with Nginx?
I'm trying to host two services on the same machine: a Next.js frontend running on port 3001, and a backend service running on port 8000. The frontend should be publicly accessible via HTTPS, while the backend should only be accessible locally (not publicly available).
I can access the frontend at https://<my-server-name>, but when I try to make a fetch request from the frontend to https://<my-server-name>/server/..., I get a mixed content error.
Here's my Nginx configuration:
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name <my-server-name>;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

# SSL support
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name <my-server-name>;

    ssl_certificate <my-cert>;
    ssl_certificate_key <my-cert-key>;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001/;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /server/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

I've tried adding upgrade headers and the X-Forwarded-Proto header, but the mixed content error persists. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?
Thanks for any help!

It seems that there is noting wrong with your nginx config. Please post more detail information. I think you send a request via ajax which do not use https protocol, because browser would not handle 301 redirect for an ajax request.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
